# Accidentally deleted Ubuntu installation, how can I reinstall it cleanly on a dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have win 7 on my machine and installed Ubuntu as dual boot. While cleaning up some unwanted files I accidentally deleted my Ubuntu installation as well. Now every time I boot my machine, I still get the dual boot option and when I try to use the Ubuntu option it says "corrupted".

Can you please advise how can I get rid of this misleading option and do a complete fresh installation?

Answer (score 0):

boot through a Live CD or USB. ask to install Ubuntu. the installer will detect the broken partition and ask to repair it. if there are no files to recognize, you will need to delete those partitions (careful, do not delete the windows partition) or re-install in them. the installer will handle the grub.